# A very basic question about geometric construction

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

[image]

I am reading Dummit and Foote's section on the geometric construction,
the author claims that the two triangles gives you $ab$ and $\frac{a}{b}$, but I really don't see how this gives you $ab$ and $a/b$.

Can someone give me some explanations?
I am really bad at this kind of geometry on the plane.

Comment: [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a line segment of length $a$ and one of length $b$, then you can construct $ab$ by drawing an (almost) arbitrary angle, marking off a distance of $1$ and $a$ on one ray, and $b$ on the other.  Draw a line segment forming a triangle with legs $1$ and $b$.  Then draw a line *parallel* to this line segment through the endpoint of $a$, intersecting the other ray and forming a similar triangle.  Then by similarity of triangles, the length cut off from the other ray is $ab$.

The same principle applies to the second diagram, just in reverse.  In both cases, you are drawing a triangle with specified side lengths, then constructing a parallel line to make a similar triangle whose corresponding side has the desired product or ratio.